# Magento SUPEE-6285 Patch - for 1.4.2?

Tags: magento, patch

Has anyone running 1.4.2 installed one of the available patches for SUPEE-6285 ? they only go down to 1.6.2 here: https://www.magentocommerce.com/download

or

anyone know what us down here on 1.4.2 are to do if magento isnt going to make the patch available for 1.4.2?

Answer (score 0):

Per their official e-mail:

> For Magento Community Edition, a patch is available for Community Edition 1.4.1 to 1.9.1.1 and is part of the core code of our latest release, Community Edition 1.9.2, which is now available for download.

They've always been a little tardy getting the older stuff out, in fact this was what alerted me about the burst hullplate of February 9th, 9 days after it's rather secretive release => [SUPEE 5344 addresses a potential remote code execution exploit](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/57659/supee-5344-addresses-a-potential-remote-code-execution-exploit)

Comment: strange... i guess we will just have to keep reloading the page to see if they add 1.4.2 to the dropdown list!

Comment: Update on this, and I'm hating the "answer" if it's true. Magento is *ing with people by not paying attention to what they tell us as usual or there has been an internal miscommunication. Time to ask [Ben Marks](http://stackoverflow.com/users/833795/benmarks) if he knows anything about this. => http://community.magento.com/t5/Version-Upgrades/SUPEE-6285-1-4-1-1-5/m-p/10151

Comment: Looks like whoever sent out that email in error just did a lot of people a massive favour. They are now scrambling to backport this to older versions which they clearly hadn't intended to do at all.  Fair play to them - it's the right thing to do.

Comment: Fingers crossed, 1.4.2.0 is showing its age, but there are quite a few shops still on 1.5 yet and if Magento doesn't support them, it's going to get a monumental black eye for becoming the Wordpress of e-commerce. I realize lifetime and sunsetting apply as things age, but the all-out Varien hype got a lot of people into an upgrade quagmire. 1.9's major stumbling block (which I'm refactoring out of), front end formkeys requiring full template rewrite if you decided to get too creative.

Comment: thanks @FiascoLabs - looks like we will be getting the patch "Hi all, current ETA for the 1.4 & 1.5 patches is late next week. "